# Has one formula the different results in server side and client side?

Tags: php, javascript

I have wrote a function to calculate the payment fee in my website but it gives different results in javascript and php. 
You should copy this code to a htm/html file.

the code in bug.php :

```
<table style="background-color:#ccc; width:600px; font-family:Tahoma">
<tbody><tr style="background-color:#00CCFF"><td>original number</td><td>phpToFixed()</td><td>jsToFixed()</td><td>phpCalc</td><td>jsCalc</td></tr>
<script>
function jsToFixed(i) {
return(Math.floor(i * 100) / 100);
}
function jsCalc(ob){
    val=jsToFixed(ob);
    if(val>0&&val!=''){
    result = jsToFixed(0.95*ob);
    }else{

    result = 0;
    }
    if(result==val&&result!=0){
    result-=0.01;
    }
return result;
}
<?php
function phpToFixed($amount){
$inp= floor($amount * 100) / 100;
return $inp;
}
function phpCalc($amount){
$inp= phpToFixed($amount);

    if($inp>0&&$inp!=''){
$result = phpToFixed($amount*0.95);

    }else{
$result = 0;
    }
if($result==$inp&&$result!=0){
$result-=0.01;
}
return $result;
}
for($i=0;$i<1;$i+=0.009){
?>
document.write("<tr><td class='org'><? echo $i; ?> </td><td class='fix'> <? echo phpToFixed($i); ?> </td><td class='fix'>"+jsToFixed(<? echo $i; ?>)+"</td><td class='calc'>"+jsCalc(<? echo $i; ?>)+"</td><td class='calc'>"+<? echo phpCalc($i); ?>+" </td></tr> ");
<?php
}
?>
</script>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Any one can figure out?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem might be helpful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When dealing with currency, ALWAYS use integer mathematics. For example, if your currency is US Dollars, ALWAYS calculate prices in cents.

Floating point numbers CANNOT represent `0.01` exactly. It's no surprise, therefore, that you're getting issues.

Whereas, integers CAN represent `1` exactly, and when you're done calculating you can just divide by 100 and [`round`](http://php.net/round) to two decimal places - any FP errors would be too small to have any effect.

Comment: Can't agree enough. Avoid floats when dealing with currency calculations as much as possible.

Comment: Often even 4 digits are used. E.g. exchange rates are always published with 4 decimal digits.